# Google script bad number format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

if i write

```
   var number = 12345678
   Logger.log(number);// outputs 1234567.0
```

but if i write

```
 var number = 12345678
   Logger.log(number);// outputs 1.2345678**E7**
```

I want to see 12345678, without dot and **E7**

How to do it??

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what the logger shows but for other use cases you can use `Utilities.formatString()` to determine how numbers are shown. The doc is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...)) and you can find more details on how to use it by [Googling printf](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=printf)

*This method can of course also be used in the logger... (to avoid any confusion about what I said above)*